# What does 'then(res => res.json())' in react-native fetch mean?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, fetch-api

What is meant by `then(res => res.json())` in the snippet below in react-native fetch?

```
fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res,
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false
        });
```

Comment: How can this be updated ? It doesn't show any effort. OP doesn't even know what `=>` is. This can be simply solved by looking on SO and documentation

Comment: res.json() in react means: when you try fetch data from a server, it will send you a RESPONSE which contains tons of irrelevant information. To target only the BODY part of the response and to convert it from JSON to javascript, you use res.json().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's not really a react question since fetch and then are parts of js itself.

fetch returns an object as Promise that contains various information like headers, HTTP status etc. etc.

You have `res.json()` and various other possibilities. `.json()` will just return the body as promise with json content.

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

You can return the data as following:

- `.arrayBuffer()`
- `.blob()`
- `.json()`
- `.text()`
- `.formData()`

Comment: Fine, but what does it mean when there is `=>` sign between `res` and `res.json()` @GottZ

Comment: thats called a lambda. thats also part of javascript. go here for more information about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @AniketSingh it's basically `.then(function(res){return res.json()})` in short.

Comment: but don't hype lambdas now. `this` will be different inside lambdas and will refer to the surrounding scope.

Comment: Move over people ;) I think this is the important part: Note that despite the method being named json(), the result is not JSON but is instead the result of taking JSON as input and parsing it to produce a JavaScript object. Why make this so ambiguous? Why not call this method toObject()?

Comment: @CharlesRobertson hey there. javascript objects can also contain recursion, methods, getters and setters, prototypical inheritance and so on. `JSON` on the other hand can only contain data types. `.fromJSON()` would be more precise I guess, thus `.json()` is fine.

Answer (score 6):

Your code part:

```
res => res.json()
```

is an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which is translated to:

```
function(res) {
    return res.json();
}
```

And, about the `json()` function:

> The `json()` method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and
> reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with the
> result of parsing the body text as JSON.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json).

Answer (score 3):

Javascript [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) function asynchronously pulls a resource from the specified `url`. Meanwhile `fetch` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). `Promise` helps with the asynchronous part and runs the function passed into `then` (`res => res.json()`) once the resource is loaded with the fetched resource as parameter. The fetched resource can be parsed using `json()` if it is JSON formatted.

`then` also returns a `Promise` making it chainable.

```
fetch(url) // asynchronously load contents of the url
           // return a Promise that resolves when res is loaded
      .then(res => res.json()) // call this function when res is loaded
      // return a Promise with result of above function
      .then(res => { // call this function when the above chained Promise resolves
        this.setState({
          data: res,
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false
        });
```

`res => res.json()` can also be written as ([*but not exactly equal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

```
function(res) { return res.json()}
```